# Extending Three20 photo gallery?

Tags: xcode4, three20, photo-gallery

Hi I am using the Three20 SDK to create a gallery and it's all working great. I basically want to extend this so that when you see a large image there is an additional button on the bottom bar (by the > keys) so you can view some text about the image - I guess this is in principal the same as on the Facebook app where you can click the comments button and the photo flips over to reveal the comments.

Ideally a tutorial on this would be amazing but I guess that probably doesn't exist so I wanted to know the best way to do this was? Should I be adding new files into the Three20 directory to add this additional functionality? Or can I do it just in the one project where I need it?

Sorry to be vague, I'm a bit new to all this!

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you shouldn't modify the three20 source code, unless it's a patch you're planning on submitting back to the three20 project.

If you need different behavior from `TTPhotoViewController`, you can subclass it and override any functions which doesn't fit your needs.

In your case, if you want to add a button to the toolbar, you should probably override (void)loadView, and replace the `_toolbar` with your own `UIToolbar`

Also, if you're only using the photo viewer from the entire three20 library, you will probably better off with a light weight solution, such as https://github.com/kirbyt/KTPhotoBrowser